# IF statement giving false positives

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a script that parses through log files, grabs a number, and compares it through AWK with a number. If that number is greater than, it is supposed to provide an echo to inform me that the number is too high.

The first portion of the codes consists of the following:

```
cat $d | grep send | awk '{print $1}' | awk '$1 > 40.0 {print $0;}' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Testing that gives me the correct item that I want.

The next portion is my IF statement. It is coded as follows:

```
if [ "$?" = "0" ]
    then
    host=$(cat $d | grep Host | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "$host has high sending usage!"
else
    echo "--" > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

My problem is that when I run this small portion, it says that both test files have high usage and I am unsure why.

```
 user@server:~/lab/CPU-Util$ ./message.sh
 Host-01 has high sending usage!
 Host-02 has high sending usage!
```

UPDATE: Updating to be more clear.

I have two files that have information such as the below:

```
 1.1.1.1
 Host-01
 five seconds: 6%/0%; one minute: 3%; five minutes: 3%
 45.58241 Mbps send  usage
 2.1677 Mbps download usage
```

If the send usage is above a set threshold, 40 for testing purposes, I want to be able to parse through it and if the "send usage" portion is above that, to give me an echo message as stated in my IF statement.

Comment: Please do let us know sample Input and expected output in CODE TAGS. so that we could help you on same.

Comment: With `if [ "$?" = 0 ]` you're testing for the previous command succeeding. It always succeeds so that test always passes. It's very unclear what you're trying to do since many of your output statements are being redirected to /dev/null and there's no obvious reason why you're using a bunch of piped commands and then switching to shell, etc.

Comment: Well that would certainly explain why this comes out as both files being positive.!

Comment: Updated my question to hopefully show what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: How are you grep-ing "hostname" from that input file? Make sure the sample input and expected output you provide are accurate and can be used to test a potential solution against.

Comment: Updated again to reflect the pattern that is used to find the Hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `if [ "$?" = 0 ]` you're testing for the previous command succeeding. It always succeeds so that test always passes.

It's very unclear what you're really trying to do since many of your output statements are being redirected to /dev/null, the posted expected output cannot be produced from the posted sample input, the posted script cannot function with the given sample input (no "hostname" that your posted command greps for), and there's no obvious reason why you're using a bunch of piped commands and then switching to shell, etc. but it MIGHT just be this:

```
awk '
/Host/ { host=$1 }
/send/ && ($1 > 40) { printf "%s has high sending usage!\n", host }
' "$d"
```

Comment: Accepted this because I was wanting the "Why" my script was giving me a false positive in which you have answered. Thank you!